# How to make matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation faster?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, imagej

I have a graph animating with matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation, but it's stupidly slow. It's been suggested that I should "export individual picture frames and then stitch them together with ImageJ."

How do I do that? Are there any good tutorials or resources that I could use?

Or are there any other ways to speed up the animation?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want suggestions about making your code run faster, post your code. Exporting the individual frames of the animation and stitching them together with external software will not be faster than just displaying the animation.

Comment: If you need advice specifically on usage of ImageJ and its plugins, please post on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/) and disclose that you're cross-posting by including a link to this question in you new post.

Comment: The speed of the animation is steered by the `interval` argument. A lower `interval` makes the animation faster. Apart this question is completely unclear. See [ask] and [mcve].